# Kmeans clustering changes for each training

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm using sklearn Kmeans algorithm for grouping in 4 clusters multiple observations and I have included init_state and seed for obtaining always the same results; but each time that I reload the code in google colab and each time I'm running the training I obtain different results in terms of number of observations in each cluster, here the code:

```
 import numpy as np
 np.random.seed(5)
 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
 kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4,init='k-means++',n_init=1,max_iter=3000,random_state=354)
 kmeans.fit(X)
 y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(X)
```

How I can obtain always the same results (in terms of the number of observation in each cluster)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's from the doc

```
If the algorithm stops before fully converging (because of ``tol`` or
``max_iter``), ``labels_`` and ``cluster_centers_`` will not be consistent,
i.e. the ``cluster_centers_`` will not be the means of the points in each
cluster. Also, the estimator will reassign ``labels_`` after the last
iteration to make ``labels_`` consistent with ``predict`` on the training
set.
```

To get a good handle of `max_iter`, see `k_means` from `scikit.cluster` Setting `return_n_iter` to `True` gets `best_n_iter` which corresponds to the number of iterations to get the best results.

Here's an example:

```
centroids, best_iter = k_means(X, n_clusters=2, init='kmeans++', random_state=0, return_n_iter=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. in scikit.cluster I'm using the kmeans and it has not the function return_n_iter. How can I do to set up return_n_iter?

Comment: Thank you. I got it. now it works correctly. Just last question on Kmeans. Is it possible to fix the maximum number of observation in a cluster?

Comment: @user3043636 You can't. Consider this. If you have 10 data points and wanted 2 clusters of size 3, what would happen to the rest of the points?

Comment: you are perfectly right. I'm not using you approach (i.e., k_means) in this way:
centroids,cluster,inertia,best_iter = k_means(X, n_clusters=4, random_state=0 ,return_n_iter=True)

when I print best_iter, it returns 7. and it gives me the number of observation for each cluster. Now, running again the code, it returns different solutions. why?

Comment: Does this mean that it is a common problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217322/discussion-between-balaji-ambresh-and-user3043636).